# Replace plot points with polygons

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I am trying to create a plot where instead of using points to represent data, I use the outline of administrative boundaries.

The below code illustrates where I am up to. Just a simple ordered scatter plot. I am now stuck, trying to replace the points with the polygon shapes for each administrative boundary (`nz_map`). Because the polygons in `nz_map` have their own geometries associated with them, I'm not sure how to position them at the locations of the points in plot space.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

```
# load packages
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)

# map of nz with administrative boundary
nz_map <- ne_states(country  = "new zealand", returnclass = "sf")

# get regions of interest and calculate area
nz_map <- nz_map %>%
  select(name, region) %>%
  filter(region %in% c("South Island", "North Island")) %>%
  mutate(area = as.vector(st_area(.)/1e6))
  

# convert to points to illustrate plotting
nz_map_pnts <- st_centroid(nz_map)

# plot
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = nz_map_pnts, aes(reorder(name, area), y = area)) +
  labs(x = "Region",
       y = "Area") +
  theme_classic()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be to use `lapply` and `annotation_custom` to add a map for each region. To this end I first create a blank plot in cartesian coordinates where I map the `name`s on `x` and the `area`s on y. Then use e.g. `lapply` to loop over the regions to add a map for the region at your desired coordinates:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)

nz_map_split <- nz_map |>
  transform(name = reorder(name, area)) |>
  split(~name)

dat <- data.frame(
  name = nz_map$name,
  area = nz_map$area
) |> 
  transform(name = reorder(name, area))

ggplot(dat, aes(name, area)) +
  geom_blank() +
  lapply(
    nz_map_split,
    \(.data) {
      #browser()
      x <- as.numeric(.data$name)
      y <- .data$area
      annotation_custom(
        ggplotGrob(ggplot(.data) +
          geom_sf() +
          theme_void()),
        xmin = x - .5, xmax = x + .5,
        ymin = y - 2000, ymax = y + 2000
      )
    }
  ) +
  labs(
    x = "Region", y = "Area"
  ) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(
      angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1
    )
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This approach preserves the relative scale of each region, a decision informed by the work of [Edward Tufte](https://www.edwardtufte.com/tufte/books_vdqi) and [Mark Monmonier](https://press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/chicago/H/bo27400568.html). It involves creating a scaled .png of each region. The workflow:

- project regions to NZTM (EPSG:2193) so coordinates are in metres and because it is the PCS most commonly used for NZ administrative data
- get the max bounding box longitude and latitude distance of regions, both not necessarily from the same region, to be used to scale output .png files
- create custom x-axis breaks to ensure scaled .png maintain a relative distance from their neighbours (to help control overlaps)
- create scaled individual .png files for each region and plot. A single colour is used in this example, but you could assign individual colours to each region when writing them if necessary

You may need to fine-tune the final `ggplot()` aesthetics to your liking, and `plot.margin` in particular. Also, `ggsave()` parameters will impact the space between each .png so this also adds some flexibility as to the size of the gap between regions. The example output image uses `width = 10` and `heigth = 6`.

Be sure to edit the path created at `png_path =` to match where you want to save the outputs. For example, edit the "C:/test/" part of `png_path = gsub(" ", "", paste0("C:/test/", name, ".png"))` to match your desired directory.

```
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggimage)

# Map of nz with administrative boundary
nz_map <- ne_states(country  = "new zealand", returnclass = "sf")

# Get regions of interest and calculate area
nz_map <- nz_map %>%
  select(name, region) %>%
  filter(region %in% c("South Island", "North Island")) %>%
  mutate(area = as.vector(st_area(.)/1e6))

# Create NZTM version of nz_map
sf_nztm <- nz_map %>%
  st_transform(2193) %>%
  group_by(area) %>%
  mutate(plot_ord = cur_group_id()) %>%
  ungroup()

# Create df to hold bbox lon/lat extent distances for scaling .png files
# and paths for saving .png
region_df <- sf_nztm %>%
  st_drop_geometry() %>%
  select(plot_ord, name, area) %>%
  arrange(plot_ord) %>%
  mutate(xmin = NA,
         xmax = NA,
         ymin = NA,
         ymax = NA,
         lon_m = NA,
         lat_m = NA,
         png_path = gsub(" ", "", paste0("C:/test/", name, ".png")))
   
# Get bbox lon/lat extent distances
for(i in seq(sf_nztm$plot_ord)) {#for(i in 1) { 
  
  # Get region polygon
  temp <- sf_nztm %>%
    filter(plot_ord == i)
  
  # Get latitude and longitude distance of temp extent
  # xmin ymin
  p1 <- st_sfc(
    st_point(c(as.numeric(st_bbox(temp)[1]),
               as.numeric(st_bbox(temp)[2])))) %>%
    st_set_crs(2193) %>%
    st_as_sf()
  
  # xmax ymin
  p2 <- st_sfc(
    st_point(c(as.numeric(st_bbox(temp)[3]),
               as.numeric(st_bbox(temp)[2])))) %>%
    st_set_crs(2193) %>%
    st_as_sf()
  
  # xmin ymax
  p3 <- st_sfc(
    st_point(c(as.numeric(st_bbox(temp)[1]),
               as.numeric(st_bbox(temp)[4])))) %>%
    st_set_crs(2193) %>%
    st_as_sf()
  
  # Get longitude (x) and latitude (y) distance
  xm <- as.numeric(st_distance(p1, p2))
  ym <- as.numeric(st_distance(p1, p3))
  
  # Add results to region_df
  region_df[i,4:9] <- list(as.numeric(st_bbox(temp)[1]),
                           as.numeric(st_bbox(temp)[3]),
                           as.numeric(st_bbox(temp)[2]),
                           as.numeric(st_bbox(temp)[4]),
                           xm, ym)
    
}

# Calculate x-axis location values for each region to help control spacing
region_df <- region_df %>%
  mutate(lon_cumu = cumsum(lon_m),
         lon_loc = (lag(lon_cumu, default = 0) + lon_cumu) / 2)

# Get max lon_m and lat_m values for defining scale of output .png extent
lon_max <- max(region_df$lon_m) / 2
lat_max <- max(region_df$lat_m) / 2
# Set scale ratio for output .png
png_ratio <- max(region_df$lon_m) / max(region_df$lat_m)
# Function to calculate lon/lat bbox centroid values
bbox_centroid <- function(minxy, maxxy) { ((maxxy - minxy) / 2) + minxy }

# Generate .png for each region
for(i in seq(region_df$plot_ord)) {
  
  lon_cent <- bbox_centroid(as.integer(region_df[i, "xmin"]), 
                            as.integer(region_df[i, "xmax"]))
  lat_cent <- bbox_centroid(as.integer(region_df[i, "ymin"]), 
                            as.integer(region_df[i, "ymax"]))
  
  temp <- sf_nztm %>%
    filter(plot_ord == i)
  
  ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data = temp, fill = "#CC79A7", colour = "black") +
    coord_sf(xlim = c(lon_cent - lon_max, lon_cent + lon_max),
             ylim = c(lat_cent - lat_max, lat_cent + lat_max),
             datum = st_crs(2193)) +
    theme(legend.position = "none",
          legend.title = element_blank(),
          axis.title = element_blank(),
          axis.text = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks = element_blank(),
          panel.grid = element_blank(),
          panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"),
          plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", color=NA))
  
  ggsave(as.character(region_df[i, "png_path"]),
         width = 5 * png_ratio, 
         height = 5,
         bg = "transparent",
         dpi = 300)
  
}

# Plot result
ggplot(region_df, 
       aes(lon_loc, area)) + 
  geom_image(aes(image = png_path), size = 0.25) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = 'off') +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = region_df$lon_loc,
                     labels = region_df$name) +
  ylim(0, 50000) +
  labs(x = "Region",
       y = "Area") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1),
        plot.margin=unit(c(1,4,1,1),"mm"))
```

[image: result]